# Javascript date validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have two text fields

```
<input type="text" name="fromdate" > (YYYY-MM-DD)

<input type="text" name="todate" > (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

Both fromdate and todate have datefields .

Dateformat is  (YYYY-MM-DD)

Among these need to validate todate textfield , date should be greater than fromdate
EX: if fromdate is 2011-11-24 todate should be greater than fromdate ,todate may 25,26 etc..,need to validate todate textfield  in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the datePicker plugin you could do:

```
$('#from').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
    }
});

$('#to').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#from').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', dateText);
    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/PAsnc/

Comment: can u send link for datepicker jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) plugin with jquery.

It has options to limit the dates to whatever day, using minDate and maxDate

Answer (score 0):

I use datejs for that : http://www.datejs.com/

Especially Date.compare

> Compares the first date to the second date and returns an number indication of their relative values. -1 = this is lessthan date. 0 = values are equal. 1 = this is greaterthan date.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good thing is to start using html5:

```
<input type="date" name="fromdate" />
<input type="date" name="todate" />
```

In Opera and chrome it will work, but for older browsers you will need a fallback [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date) and [here with modernizr](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-types), like suggested by other users.